# .split() no hace su funcion

Tags: python

Estoy usando la funcion .split() en python pero cuando ejecuto este codigo me da una lista con la palabra entera `output:["Palabra"]` en vez de la lista deseada con cada letra en un indice `output:["P","a","l","a"...]`. El input the estoy metiendo a la funcion son listas sacados de un csv file, pero eso no debería tener imortancio ya que las estoy convirtiendo en string en la linea `word_to_split = str(word[0])`, y esto esta confirmado que funciona ya que al `print(word_to_split)` sale como un string normal y corrient¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
def wordPicker(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        chosen_row = random.choice(list(reader))
        return chosen_row

def wordSplitter(word):
    word_to_split = str(word[0])
    split_word = word_to_split.split()
    return split_word
```

Comment: Agrega los datos con que probastes, la salida deseada y la salida que obtienes.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de concepto sobre lo que supuestamente hace `str.split()`.

El método `.split()` de las cadenas sirve para separar una cadena dada por los lugares en que aparezca un cierto carácter, que le tienes que pasar como parámetro a `.split()`.

Si no le pasas ningún parámetro, entonces usará por defecto cualquier carácter considerado como "espacio", que es, además del propio espacio, el retorno de carro, el tabulador y otros caracteres unicode de separación (indistinguibles a simple vista del espacio).

Puedes ver que funciona de este modo si la cadena que le pasas efectivamente tiene espacios:

```
>>> cadena = "Esto es una prueba"
>>> cadena.split()
['Esto', 'es', 'una', 'prueba']
```

Si la cadena que le pasas no tiene espacios, obviamente te devolverá una lista con la misma cadena otra vez (que es el resultado de dividirla por donde aparezcan los espacios):

```
>>> cadena = "Holaquetal"
>>> cadena.split()
['Holaquetal']
```

Si le pasas a `.split()` una cadena como parámetro, dividirá por los lugares en que aparezca esa cadena:

```
>>> cadena = "Holaquetal"
>>> cadena.split("ue")
['Holaq', 'tal']
```

### Solución

Lo que tú quieres hacer es convertir la cadena en una lista:

```
>>> cadena = "Holaquetal"
>>> list(cadena)
['H', 'o', 'l', 'a', 'q', 'u', 'e', 't', 'a', 'l']
```